# Dynamic Target Application

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

For any reasons I have 3 targets/scheme each one to load a different theme. So, when I run snapshot command it only take the snapshot of the target selected into Target Application (UITest Target).

[image: Target]

Is there a way to deal with it dynamically? I wanna run snapshot command and get the result of 3 themes/targets/scheme.

Issue: https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/issues/348

Comment: No you can't, you need to add 3 different classes for each target

Comment: 1 different classes for each "uitest target" (classic, exclusive, prime), right?

Answer (score 0):

The way I accomplished this was by creating a base test bundle with NONE target and one test bundle for each individual app target.  I implemented the common test in the base bundle.

In each individual/flavor target, if the test were the same as the base, I extended the test class from my base test class instead of XCTest directly.  This way they all use the same test where they are similar and can extend to specific testing only where they are different.